# Arrays with 3 positive integers that sum to n

Tags: python

I have created a generator using `itertools` `combinations_with_replacement` which returns all the combinations of 3 positive integers that sum to n:

```
def combinations(n):
    for combo in combinations_with_replacement([i for i in range(1,n+1)],3):
        if sum(combo) == n:
            yield(combo)
```

e.g. `combinations(7)` returns `(1, 1, 5) (1, 2, 4) (1, 3, 3) (2, 2, 3)`
Unfortunately this quickly becomes very slow with larger values of n. Is there an alternative way of doing this which is more efficient? I have tried using for loops although every time I get duplicate combinations. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to get all the combinations of *three* numbers. You can just get combinations of *two* numbers, and you know what the third number has to be.

```
>>> n = 100
>>> combs_of_three = [(a,b,c) for (a,b,c) in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, n+1), 3) if a+b+c == n]
>>> combs_of_two = [(a,b,n-a-b) for (a,b) in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, n+1), 2) if n-a-b >= b]
>>> combs_of_three == combs_of_two
True
```

This is much faster:

```
>>> %timeit [(a,b,c) for (a,b,c) in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, n+1), 3) if a+b+c == n]
9.97 ms ± 97.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit [(a,b,n-a-b) for (a,b) in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, n+1), 2) if n-a-b >= b]
359 µs ± 2.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive function: choose a number that fits; then recur on the remaining size and total.

```
import math

def partition(total, size=3, lowest=1):
    if size == 1:
        return [[total]]
    else:
        result = []

        # At each choice, pick no less than a "fair" proportion of the remaining total.
        #    This avoids duplicating combinations.
        limit = math.ceil(total / size)

        # Iterate `i` through the range [ limit, total-(size-1) ], inclusive
        for i in range(limit, total-size+2):
            for shorter in partition(total-i, size-1):
                result.append(shorter + [i])
    return result

print(partition( 7, 3))
print(partition(12, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 5]]
[[4, 4, 4], [3, 5, 4], [2, 6, 4], [1, 7, 4], [3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 5], [1, 6, 5], [3, 3, 6], [2, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 7], [1, 4, 7], [2, 2, 8], [1, 3, 8], [1, 2, 9], [1, 1, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, this is an extremely complex algorithm and would quickly sum up to `O(n ^ 3)`

The "algorithm" itself probably won't get a lot more efficient than `O(n ^ 2)`, but you could change it to `O(n ^ 2)` fairly easily.

```py
def combinations(n):
   for i in range(n - 2): # go up to n and add 1 + 1, assuming you don't want 0 and 0
       for j in range(n - 2): # the same again.
           if i + j >= n:
               continue
           yield (i, j, n - i - j) # there are probably more than just these, keep that in mind.
```

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Another optimization with [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse):

```
In [383]: def combinations_1(n):
     ...:     for combo in combinations_with_replacement([i for i in range(1, n+1)], 3):
     ...:         if sum(combo) == n:
     ...:             yield(combo)
     ...:             
     ...:             
     ...:             

In [384]: def combinations_2(n):
     ...:     return itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2] == n, \
     ...:            combinations_with_replacement(range(1,n+1), 3)) 
     ...:            

In [385]: %timeit list(combinations_1(17))
5.9 ms ± 322 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [386]: %timeit list(combinations_2(17))
289 µs ± 28.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```